# Google Chrome - no space on rootfs partition

Tags: partition, disk-usage, chrome, root-filesystem

I've managed to install `google-chrome` on *Debian Wheezy*. My `rootfs` is only *320MB* because I didn't predict that some day I would install *Google Chrome*, which has more than *100MB* and installs in `/opt` (`opt` is part of `rootfs`). I successfully installed `google-chrome`, but I can't update it with `apt-get` since `rootfs` usage is **~99%**.

What should I do if I don't want to resize `rootfs`? Is there any safe way to install `google-chrome` in a non-standard place (e.g. in `/usr`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have free disk space (Partition, LVM) then you can mount it at `/opt`. If not then you can move `/opt` to e.g. `/usr/opt` and create a symlink in the rootfs. Or you make a bind mount (via `fstab`): `mount --bind /usr/opt /opt`