# No space left to free up on rootfs partition to upgrade kernel

Tags: kernel, partition, upgrade, disk-usage, root-filesystem

I want to upgrade [Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) from `3.16` to `4.3`. Unfortunately when I run `aptitude install linux-image-4.3.0-1-amd64` installation fails due to no space on `rootfs` partition. *117MB* left, *174MB* needed.

I have no old kernels to remove to free up more disk space (except the one that I'm using right now):

```
root@host:/# aptitude search linux-image | grep ^i
ip  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64      - Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
```

I tried to [free up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) space using `aptitude clean`, `apt-get autoremove`, but it didn't help because `/var` is a separate partition. AFAIK those commands removes content of the `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory, so it cannot help.

I considered to temporarily `mount --bind / /home/rootfs` (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116400/google-chrome-no-space-on-rootfs-partition)), but `rootfs` probably [cannot be safely remounted](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2008-September/067244.html).

My file system disk space usage:

```
root@host:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       454M  310M  117M  73% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G   19M  1,6G   2% /run
/dev/sda7        23G   13G  8,8G  59% /usr
tmpfs           3,9G   52M  3,9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       250G  187G   64G  75% /media/Windows/C
/dev/sda5       500G  428G   73G  86% /media/Windows/D
/dev/sda2        96M   25M   72M  26% /boot/efi
/dev/sda8       7,3G  966M  5,9G  14% /var
/dev/sda9        14G   37M   13G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda11      126G   95G   25G  80% /home
tmpfs           797M   20K  797M   1% /run/user/112
tmpfs           797M   24K  797M   1% /run/user/1000
```

`du -mx / | sort -n` result: [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/uzesTxwU8qdqwwyYjBhTmE).

OS version:

```
root@host:/# cat /etc/debian_version 
stretch/sid
```

`/boot` content:

```
root@host:/# du -sh /boot/*
156K    /boot/config-3.16.0-4-amd64
25M     /boot/efi
8,8M    /boot/grub
16M     /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
16M     /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64.old-dkms
2,6M    /boot/System.map-3.16.0-4-amd64
3,0M    /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

- Is there any clever and safe way to free up `rootfs` partition or temporarily move current kernel to another partition?
- Is it safe to move some `rootfs` content to another partition and create symbolic links pointing to them?

I know that there is [plenty of similar problems](https://www.google.pl/search?q=no%20space%20kernel%20upgrade), but [most of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot) end up with removing old kernels which I don't have.

Comment: Sometimes there are old files in /boot from previous kernels left which you can delete safely. Please list `/boot`.

Comment: I added `/boot` content to my question. It seems that those files belongs to currently installed kernel.

Comment: I believe your best bet is to extend the `/boot` partition. I'm pretty sure it has to be a separate, primary partition. Here Fedora suggested 500MiB, and that seems to be roomy but not overly so (3 kernels plus assorted junk fit comfortably).

Comment: Please post your `/etc/fstab`. Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: AFAIK You can at least delete the `*.old-dkms` file if you current system boots without problem - it is just a backup / failback file.

Comment: `/bin` and `/sbin` have historically been at `/` always for a strong reason. run `whereis mount`

Comment: I have more than one time removed the older running kernel to install a new one while I do not implement a more definitive solution.

Comment: @jofel No! `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/lib` and `/etc` need to be on the root partition, because they contain files that are needed to mount the other partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

450MB is not much for a root+boot partition on a modern amd64 system. If you want to install multiple kernels, you're going to have to reorganize your partitions. Even if you don't, it's pretty tight.

Given the partitions you have now, I suggest moving the root partition to what is now `/var`. Since you're going to move the root partition, boot from rescue media (e.g. [SystemRescueCD](https://www.sysresccd.org/)). Mount `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda8`, say to `/media/sda6` and `/media/sda8`. Then:

1. Create a `/var` directory: `mkdir /media/sda8/var`
2. Move everything in the old `/var` partition to this new subdirectory: `mv /media/sda8/* /media/sda8/var` (`/var` itself will be skipped)
3. Move everything except `/boot` from the old root partition to the old var partition: `mv /media/sda6/[^bv]* /media/sda6/bin /media/sda8/`
4. There should only be `/boot` and an empty `/var` on the old root partition. Move everything from `/boot` to the root of the partition: `mv /media/sda6/boot/* /media/sda6`
5. Remove the spurious directories: `rmdir /media/sda6/boot /media/sda6/var` and create one that's now needed: `mkdir /media/sda8/boot`
6. Edit the `fstab` file (now in `/media/sda8/etc/fstab`), remove the entry for `/var`, add one for `/boot`, and correct the entry for `/` if necessary.
7. Update the bootloader configuration. The easy way to get it right is to run both `update-grub` script (to regenerate `grub.cfg`) and `grub-install` (to regenerate the first-stage bootloader so that it knows where to find the rest, including `grub.cfg`). But to do that, you need to present it the right directory tree.

   ```
   mount --rbind /dev /media/sda8/dev
   mount --rbind /proc /media/sda8/proc
   mount --rbind /sys /media/sda8/sys
   mount --bind /media/sda6 /media/sda8/boot
   chroot /media/sda8
   mount /usr
   update-grub
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

Now reboot.

Alternatively, you could move `/boot` to `/var`; but it's a less common configuration, so you may have to tweak some bootloader configuration files.

These days, separating `/usr` from `/` is pretty pointless. Separating `/var` from `/` has never been really useful (they both need to be mounted read-write on most setups).

In the future, I recommend using LVM for Linux partitions. It's a lot more flexible.

Comment: I followed those steps and after reboot I've got `error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod' not found. Entering rescue mode...` which is probably result of wrong `/etc/fstab`. I've changed 2 lines of `/etc/fstab` - one for `/dev/sda8` (which used to be mounted as `/var`) and one for `/dev/sda6` (which used to be mounted as `/`). Before: `UUID=SDA8_UUID_HERE /var ext4 defaults 0 2`, `UUID=SDA6_UUID_HERE / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`. After: `UUID=SDA8_UUID_HERE / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`, `UUID=SDA6_UUID_HERE /boot vfat defaults 0 1`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @patryk.beza Grub is looking for a file in `/boot`, but if `/boot` is in a separate partition, then the path should be `/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod`. I think the `prefix` setting is wrong, it should be something like `(hd0,0)/grub/grub.cfg`. Normally running `grub-install` should take care of setting it correctly so that you don't need to set it in `grub.cfg`. In fact setting it in `grub.cfg` is too late since that's where Grub looks for `grub.cfg`. My bad, I forgot to mention this: I think you need to rerun `grub-install /dev/sda`. Could you try this and report back?

Comment: It worked! I really appreciate your help @Gilles. A few notes: I needed to run `chroot /media/sda8 /bin/bash` because by default it tried to use `/bin/zsh`; I needed to mount `/boot` with `ext4`, *not* `vfat` (as I wrongly suggested above); don't know why, but `grub-install` wiped out Windows' dual boot options - I probably need to add them manually. BTW: [SystemRescueCD](https://www.sysresccd.org/) is great tool.